# Dynamically disabling <option> elements based on amount selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, listbox

I have provided a user with an interface where they can select from 30 options(hardcoded), displayed in a **bootstrap dualListBox.**

This works perfectly however I would like to set the max amount of options that can be selected to 10.
After which, all the options that could have been selected on the left side, become disabled.

Should the user remove a selected option, the others can then become available for selection again.

I realize that I will be using jquery to achive this, however I am unsure as to how I will count the amount selected and how I will target remaining selections to disable or make them available again.

Is there any advice on how to correctly solve this problem?

The plugin I am using for the dual listbox can be found here:

[Bootstrap dualListBox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/)

Answer (score 0):

First I would bind a change event, then I would check if the number of selected items is equal or exceeds then max number of elements, if so I will disable it.
If I understand your question correct it would be something like:

```
$('#selector-id').on('change', function(e){
var selectedElements = $(this).val();
if(selectedElements && selectedElements.length >= 10){
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
} else {
$(this).prop('disabled', false);
}
});
```

(This is not tested code)

Comment: I have tested this. The on('change') event calls successfully however nothing happens if I select more than 10

Comment: Hmm it does work, but you can't change it after that, I didn't think of that... : https://jsfiddle.net/s0zwg7td/

Comment: Im sorry, I just saw the link to bootstrap dualListBox. When the user click's on a item in the second selectbox you will need to re-enable the first selecbox with `$('#selector-id').prop('disabled', false');`, I hope this helps.

Comment: I will test this tommorow and then mark your question if it works.As I have run out of time